# How to create a strip-like chart with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to create a plot with matplotlib so when the window is maximized, the plot only occupies a strip of the screen? As an example, please consider the example below. In this case, I want to arrange the 3 subplots in an horizontal line, and I would like to keep the size small, that is why I added 2 rows with blank subplots. When I use figsize the window that pops does have the specified size, but once it's maximized, matplotlib re-fits the subplots to occupy the entire screen. I would like matplotlib to redraw the contents to fit this "strip", not the other way round.

Thus, is it possible to create the strip directly, without un-wanted resizes from matplotlib and without adding all these innecessary blank subplots to do the trick?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I am running this program using Python 3.5 and Matplotlib 2.2.3. The interactive backend is TkAgg.

[image]

Comment: You don't specify *how* you are visualizing this plot. What system? What backend?

Comment: Don't have time to write full answer, but I think one option would be to embed your plot in a simple application (e.g. https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html) and constrain the width/height ratio of your window.

Comment: I added information about the library version and the backend, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib's subplot grids are positionned in units relative to the figure size. Positionning subplots in absolute coordinates hence requires some tweaking.
You could define the width and height of the grid in inches and then calculate the margins of the grid each time the figure is resized.
In the following the grid always stays 4 inch wide and 1 inch tall, no matter the figure size.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True)
for ax in axes:
    ax.plot(np.arange(30), np.cumsum(np.random.randn(30)))

# set width and height in physical units (inches)
width = 4 # inch
height= 1 # inch
def resize(evt=None):
    w,h = fig.get_size_inches()
    l = ((w-width)/2.)/w
    b = ((h-height)/2.)/h
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=l, right=1.-l, bottom=b, top=1.-b)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


resize()    
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", resize)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain about your visualisation approach.
So according to me you can try subplot for it.
see how subplot works here (https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT

fig = PLT.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot([(1, 2), (3, 4)], [(4, 3), (2, 3)])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2.plot([(7, 2), (5, 3)], [(1, 6), (9, 5)])

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3.plot([(7, 2), (5, 3)], [(1, 6), (9, 5)])

PLT.show()
```